# scikit learn on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

[image]

I tried to run something on jupyter notebook and I got this problem.
 does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Show us the code where you define load_breast_cancer(). The message says it can't be found.

Comment: i didn't. that's the only code and the datasets are in the sklearn file where it should be. 
how do I define it?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load the dataset without having imported it first.
You need to import `sklearn datasets`.

---

**Use this:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

data = load_breast_cancer()
```

---

This should work fine.